# Why would Google rank my website for an irrelevant search term based on a site search result?

Tags: seo, google

My website search string result is on top of Google for some reason

For example: security officer chest camera

We don't sell these cameras, but we are on the top of the Google search results.  The URL that Google has found is a site search link on the website: `example.co.uk/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=security+officer+chest+camera`

Can someone explain why Google picked this up and we on top of Google

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are asking, though I think I do. Do you allow Google to crawl your site search?? If so, you need to stop this immediately before Google punishes your site.

Comment: the full site is crawled by google but how did google pick that up. Because ive not made a link for it or searched it

Comment: Apparently Google found it. It does not matter how. You want to mark any site search result pages as *noindex* or restrict them in robots.txt fast. Google severely punishes sites that fill their index with search result pages and have for a long time. It is just a matter of time before Google gets mad. Do not wait for that day. You will not be able to undo it quickly.

Comment: You seem to have "About 568" search results pages indexed by Google. You may not sell those cameras, however, your search returns 3 pages of results for that search phrase on your site. It's quite possible that anyone (or anything) has auto-generated links to your search results pages (perhaps for the purpose of aggregating shopping/products results?).

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled your onsite search results to be indexable. As such your site will return essentially **blank results to bots following keywords**. This will work against you in Google's rankings as Google does punish 'thin pages' such as these.

Simple fix: **Block indexing for all your internal site searches.**